# TypeError: format.replace is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, http, datepicker

My DatePicker was working until today. Suddenly the wholeDatePicker is white when opening it and it gives me tihs error:

```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: format.replace is not a function
TypeError: format.replace is not a function
    at expandFormat (moment.js:543:29)
    at formatMoment (moment.js:527:18)
    at Moment.format (moment.js:3994:22)
    at MomentDateAdapter.format (material-moment-adapter.mjs:126:21)
    at MatDatepickerInput._formatValue (datepicker.mjs:2907:47)
    at MatDatepickerInput._assignValueProgrammatically (datepicker.mjs:2938:14)
    at MatDatepickerInput.writeValue (datepicker.mjs:2846:14)
    at onChange (forms.mjs:3160:27)
    at forms.mjs:3646:50
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at zone.js:1282:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26218:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:35)
```

I can't find `format.replace` anywhere in my code and according to the console the issue isn't in my code? I am confused as to why this error suddenly occurs.

Here's my DatePicker HTML code:

```
    <input mat-input [matDatepicker]="basicDatepicker" id="invisibleDate" readonly="readonly" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="currentDate">
    <h4 id="datePicker">{{ currentDate | customDate }}</h4>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="basicDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #basicDatepicker id="datePickerIcon"></mat-datepicker>
```

[This is what my DatePicker looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vytX.png)

Comment: Can you show the component as well pls?

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it started happening around the same time too.
Do you know what happened? Just need to update something?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the luxon equivalent of this error while testing React code with testing-library.

```
dtf.format(...).replace is not a function
TypeError: dtf.format(...).replace is not a function
```

I can see moment.js in your error so the problem is probably very similar as luxon is the new alternative to momentjs.

For us it was a timezone related issue.
This was the particular function that failed when it was called from the tests:

```
DateTime.fromISO(date,
{ zone: timezone, locale: I18n.locale }).toFormat('EEE dd MMM, HH:mm')
```

Our workaround was that we don't pass timezone as props to our components in the tests.

If it's a code implementation issue then try to look for timezone related things in your code.

If it's a package that this problem occurs in I guess it's worth raising it as a bug on their side.